# Your login methods to website

Tags: support, openid, login

I'm not sure if its just me, but every time I want to sign in to the site, I have to go through the whole OpenID process and link my account. I think it would just make it easier for everyone if you just added a separate log-in with user name and password to the site for people who already made and linked their accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign in with Google, Yahoo or Facebook, you can check something along the lines of "remember me". StackOverflow et al will remember you until your login cookies expire or are deleted.

Comment: I understand that concept but in my position where I use different computers all day its just annoying...Its ok it was just a suggestion.